# Limits of a vector proof

Tags: vectors

If $x_n, x, y$ are vectors in $R^m$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$, prove that $\langle x_n, y\rangle \rightarrow \langle x, y \rangle$.

I am assuming one can simply say that $x_n$ $\rightarrow$ $x$ so we get the result but I don’t understand how vectors work and an explanation of how this proof works would go a long way.

Comment: Do you know how inner products are defined in $\mathbb R^{m}$?

Comment: They would be defined as $x_1$$y_1$ + ... + $x_n$$y_n$

Comment: Try to write out a proof for the case $m=2$. I am sure you are capable of ansewering this question yourself.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and $\|x_n - x\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$:
\begin{align*}
|\langle x_n, y \rangle - \langle x, y \rangle |
= |\langle x_n - x, y \rangle| \leq \|x_n - x\|\|y\| \to 0 
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: It is better to just write down the inner products and use convergence of each coordinate.